# How to display a LinkedHashMap < string, LinkedHashMap <string, string>> on Android

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, hashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap of contacts. For each contact I save inside the LinkedHashMap , a new LinkedHashMap with a variable amount of results of an Action. For example,

```
Contact 1(Key)
  Action1(Key) - 2/10(Value)
  Action2 - 3/10
  .....
  Action10 - 3/5
Contact 2
  Action1 - 2/10
  Action2 - 3/10
  Action3 - 4/3
```

How I am going to put them in the following order like:

```
         Action1   Action2   Action3 ..... Action10 
Contact1 result 
Contact2
```

To display them in gridview or tablelayout or webview?

I am trying with following to access elements but I get all of them in the arraylist

```
ArrayList Valuestrings = new ArrayList();
ArrayList KValuestrings = new ArrayList();    

for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> entry : LnkHshPlayerData.entrySet())
            {

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : entry.getValue().entrySet())
                {

                    KValuestrings.add(entry2.getKey());
                    Valuestrings.add(entry2.getValue());
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure it's what you ask for but if you do:

ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> selects = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();


    for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : selects.entrySet()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            strings.add(entry2.getValue());
        }
    }
gridViewAdapter.addAll(strings);
```

Comment: In second loop says he finds an object and not String, String

Comment: if you copy/paste my code it should work, i tested it with fake data, and it work perfect.